# FILE_URI is not displaying image when app is re-opened ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Im developing a IOS app in ionic .

Im using cordova camera plugin as stated in [this](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/use-android-ios-camera-ionic-framework/) tutorial and got FILE_URI of image, and is working fine when i'm displaying it in img tag..

But when I close and re-open the app , Image is not showing. I'm not getting what's wrong is going on..

Can anybody suggest me the correct answer?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and used local storage to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for your answer.

The problem with the camera api is, whenerver we upload the image from session to session we will get the same image link . we have to change the name of the image such that it will differentiate between old Image and new Image..

Detailed explanation and solution is [here](http://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/)..